# Coin flip error node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a command for my discord bot and i need a bit of help, it should to be a command to flip a coin and you choose between heads or tails and it tells you if you win or lose, here`s what i have so far:

```
var coins = [ //for the coin command
  "heads",
  "tails"
  ];

  "coin": {
  proc: function(bot,msg,args) {
    coinz = coins[Math.floor(Math.random() * coins.length)];
    if (args === "heads" || args === "tails" || !`${args}` === `${coinz}`) {
    msg.channel.send(`Your bet: \`${args}\`, outcome: \`${coinz}\` you lose`)}
    else if (args === "heads" || args === "tails" || `${args}` === `${coinz}`) {
    msg.channel.send(`Your bet: \`${args}\`, outcome: \`${coinz}\` you win`);
         } else return msg.channel.send('Must be either `sr!heads` or `sr!tails`').then(msg=>msg.delete(5000));
       }
     },


// this is obviously not the full code, just what is needed to be seen!
```

here is an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant code on the question, instead of links and images

Comment: The rules of stack overflow require that all code that is relevant to the question be pasted into the actual question and formatted appropriately.  This is because external links tend to change or get broken over time rendering the question useless as a reference for  future visitors (which is an important goal for stack overflow).

Comment: What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your conditional set up incorrect. if args is heads or tails its going to trigger the you lose. Try setting it up like this.

```
if (args === "heads" || args === "tails"){
  if(args != coinz) {
    // Display you lose message
  }
  else {
    // Display you win message
  }
} 
else {
   // Display incorrect input
}
```